# If statement inside criteriaBuiilder

Tags: java, criteria

I have something like that:

```
    criteria.select(something.get("somethingId"))
            .where(builder.and(
                    builder.equal(something.get("firstColumn"), firstValue),
                    builder.equal(something.get("thirdColumn", thirdValue), 
            ));
```

and want to do add into where something like this:

```
secondValue != 0 ? builder.equal(something.get("secondColumn"), secondValue) : DONOTHING;
```

So shortly: if the value of secondValue is different than "0" i don't want to set builder.equal(secondColumn). And I want to use that if inside builder if it is possible because this builder will be really long so I want to avoid code duplication.

The problem is that this if condition cannot be empty after semicolon and from the other hand I cannot use normal if(secondValue != 0) inside this builder expression.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Unfortunately it not works as expect. event method builder.equal(secondValue, secondValue) is not proper ("cannot resolve method ('int','int)

Comment: Ah, I should have looked at [the docs of CriteriaBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) before posting that comment.. You're indeed right that the `.equals` expects an `Expression<?>` as first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pattern I find usefull for building JPA criterias is to use a List to add predicates into. That allows you to add some of them conditionally a lot more easily:

```
List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();

predicateList.add(builder.equal(something.get("firstColumn"), firstValue));
predicateList.add(builder.equal(something.get("thirdColumn", thirdValue));
if(secondValue != 0) {
    predicateList.add(builder.equal(something.get("secondColumn", secondValue));
}

criteria.select(something.get("somethingId"))
        .where(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]);
```

Note that if you add multiple predicates as an Array to the `where` method of  `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery` they will automatically be added as a conjunction, so wrapping all of them in a `builder.and` is not necessary.